# Is there a max buffer size for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my activity class I have a for loop that parses a XML script and dumps that data into an  `EditText` (that is scrollable).

I am writing the contents on to this `EditText` console on a UI thread. For some reason, the console wont print all of the commands in my XML script.

It stops after a while. So I am wondering if there is any limit for `EditText` and is there a way to come over it so that I can dump in loads of text into an `EditText`?

Comment: Of how many lines of parsed XML are we talking here?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the EditText with a TextView and it works...
I still could not figure out the issue with EditText though.